# Unable to send more than 10 emails with nodemailer with yahoo smtp server

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer, yahoo-mail

I have been trying to send bulk emails (around 10 - 20 emails a day) with nodemailer. But I found that my code always generate `554 6.6.0 Error sending message for delivery`. May I get some insights please?
For what is worth, my transporter setting is as follows:

```
const transporter = {
  host: "smtp.mail.yahoo.com",
  port: 587,
  service: "yahoo",
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: user@yahoo.com,
    // create in the yahoo account - security settings
    pass: user.password,
  },
  logger:true,
  debugger:true
};
```

Comment: I have a loop to initiate with a new transporter and close the transporter with `transporter.close()` after sending every email. However, from my observation, every 10th or 11th email would fail.

Comment: Sounds more like your mail server/providers says "no no, your a bad gay".

Comment: oh, I found that my program is sending too many requests in a second, so after I added a timeout of around 30 seconds, it seems to be running seamlessly